# Storing a JSON object to a C++ map

Tags: c++, json, dictionary

I'm in need of help from you guys.

At present I'm using cJSON to parse data formatted to Json standard.

The data below is an example of the data.

```
{
    "time" : {              
        "timezone" : string,
        "ntpservers" : array<string>
    },
    "datetime" : {
        "value" : "2013-10-23 03:35:45.182042",
        "space-custom-class" : "datetime.datetime"
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to break the data down to key value pairs 
and store them in the map.  I can see that "time" is a key but the value is a dictionary so how do I store this as a value of "time" and this goes for the "datetime" key.  I know that there's some iteration involved, but I'm stuck.  Because the value can be a primitive type, array or a dictionary should the value be a generic object like a template?
Some example would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: it's not clear to me whether you don't know how to render a json object in a std::map (not possible without an "item" abstraction and polymorphism) or if you don't know how to create a tree representation with cJSON.

Answer (score 4):

[JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) has many C++ JSON parser libraries listed that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at boost::property_tree it will save you on having to code it yourself.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/property_tree.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about which dependencies you can use in project, therefore my answer may be not accepted for you.

In Qt5 exist some classes that can write JSON such as you want. This is a small example for demonstration this:

```
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QJsonObject topQuery;
    topQuery["objectType"] = QString("objects.Word");

    QJsonObject parameters;
    parameters["language"] = QString("en");
    parameters["to"] = QString("ru");
    parameters["rate"] = 0;
    parameters["isInput"] = true;

    topQuery["query"] = parameters;

    QJsonObject sortParameter;
    sortParameter["sortBy"] = QString("rate");
    sortParameter["direction"] = QString("desc");

    QJsonArray sortArray;
    sortArray.append(sortParameter);

    topQuery["sort"] = sortArray;
    topQuery["limit"] = 10;

    QJsonDocument document(topQuery);
    qDebug() << document.toJson();
}
```

Result of this code will be:

```
{
    "limit": 10,
    "objectType": "objects.Word",
    "query": {
        "isInput": true,
        "language": "en",
        "rate": 0,
        "to": "ru"
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "direction": "desc",
            "sortBy": "rate"
        }
    ]
}
```

For Qt4 also exist library with the simular api: http://qjson.sourceforge.net/.

Before I also was looking for C++ lib without dependencies for creating json, like stl::map, but I found only a Qt variant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very cryptic. This is how to do it with cJson:

```
cJSON *current_element = NULL;
char *current_key = NULL;

cJSON_ArrayForEach(current_element, object)
{
    current_key = current_element->string;
    if (current_key != NULL)
    {
        /* do something with the key */
    }
}
```

reference: https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON/issues/167